# Should I create Firestore index for iOS app

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got collection called cities, every city document got **is_favorite** boolean flag and also **order** number field. I want to use it this way

```
 db.collection("cities")
        .whereField("is_favorite", isEqualTo: true)
        .order(by: "order", descending: false)
        .getDocuments {}
```

But I receive this error

> Firestore error The query requires an index.

Same time both of this constructions are working fine

```
 db.collection("cities")
        .whereField("is_favorite", isEqualTo: true)
        .getDocuments {}

 db.collection("cities")
        .order(by: "order", descending: false)
        .getDocuments {}
```

So why should I care about Firestore index if I use both queries together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some operations, like queries with multiple arguments (in the top one you use both `where` and `order`), you will need firebase to generate an index for you so it can easily query by both of those arguments.

To do that, go to your firestore dashboard in the firebase console and navigate to the indexes tab. Creating the index may take a few minutes on first run but you will only have to do this once.

Comment: so i won't be able to combine sorting and filtering with randomly selected fields in future before creating special index for them?

Comment: I believe there is a way to programmatically create those indexes. Which means you may have a lot of them. That said, most basic queries are automatically created.

Comment: Great answer Carlo. Indexes on single fields are indeed created automatically. For some queries on multiple fields, Firestore may be able to combine the existing indexes too (in a so-called [zig-zag-merge join](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection)). But when you get a message about needing an index, you will need to create it manually. Note that most SDKs will log a URL that takes you directly to a page to create the necessary index (with everything pre-populated). This saves you have to fill out the form yourself, so be sure to check for that URL in your logs.